# Resolving promises in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, es6-promise

I am having trouble getting promises to work the way I need.  I have tried many different ways to resolve the promise but nothing I have done will work as I need.  I am trying to get drag and drop of file working on a web page.  I need a list of all the files in a Set (this.files) that is passed to a call to upload the files.  The problem is that the Promise.all is being run before the promises are completed.

I am still struggling to wrap my mind around promises so maybe I have it all wrong but it seems from all my research this should work.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
  async dndDropFiles(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let ptable = [];
    this.files = new Set();
    if (event.dataTransfer.types[0] === "Files") {
      var items = event.dataTransfer.items;
      for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
        // webkitGetAsEntry is where the magic happens
        var item = await items[i].webkitGetAsEntry();
        if (item) {
          ptable.push(new Promise(async resolve => {
            resolve(await this.dndTraverseFileTree(item, ""));
          }))
        }
      }  
      Promise.all(ptable)
        .then( (results) => {
          if (this.files.size > 0) {
            this.progress = this.uploadService.upload(this.files, this.currentDir, this.currentProject);
          }    
        })
    }
  }

  async dndTraverseFileTree(item, path) {
    if (item.isFile) {
      // Get file
      item.file((file) => {
        this.files.add(file);
      });
  } else if (item.isDirectory) {
      // Get folder contents
      let ptable = [];
      var dirReader = await item.createReader();
      dirReader.readEntries((entries) => {
        for (var i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
          ptable.push(new Promise( async resolve => {
            resolve(await this.dndTraverseFileTree(entries[i], path + item.name + "/"));
          }));
        }
        Promise.all(ptable)
          .then (results => {});
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: wow what microtask magic: `new Promise(async resolve1 => resolve(await new Promise(resolve2 => resolve2()))` - just wonder do you need this microtask magic or do you mean to `(new Promise(r=>r())).then(r=>r)` ?

Comment: I had tried it with out the async but it didn't work either.  Do you think that it would affect the resolving of the Promise?

Comment: the thing is you kinda mix async sugar with promise then and also create redundant promises - i give it a shoot and rewrite your code

Comment: I pull all the async and await from the functions and I don't see anything really different.  I still see all the files from comments I have put in but it still resolves the Promise.all before the promises are done.  I have to be doing something wrong with the way I am resolving the promises.

Comment: Do you want to loop all files in directory recursively and then add them in array, after that upload them? But you need to wait all of them to be added at once because each `item.file()` is async? I would return a new `new Promise()` in `item.file()` instead, and then catch it with a variable like `let promise = item.file(() => return new Promise(() => //add file here and call resolve))` and then add `ptable.push(promise)`. At the very end I would use `Promise.all()`. I don't have a clear structure in mind, but if you can create a Sandbox-like example that is similar, I could try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It feels like you are making things a bit too difficult, and I suggest another good read into coding standards and the way Promises work :) The async/await construct has been introduced to increase code readability.

Anyways, I have some untested code here. But it should do the trick. Also I strongly advise you to add typings. You are using angular, so I can only assume you are using TypeScript. With typings you will make less errors, and the compiler helps you along the way.

Before I give the code, this `webkitGetAsEntry` is non standard. And should only be used if you really don't want to target old browsers or safari/ios:

> Non-standard
>   This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

But, you could go about it like this. First function to process the event. The second one to traverse the tree:

```
async dndDropFiles(event: DragEvent): Promise<void> {
  if (event.dataTransfer.types[0] !== "Files" || !event.dataTransfer.items) {
    return;
  }

  const entries = [...(event.dataTransfer.items as any)].map(
    item => item.webkitGetAsEntry()
  );

  const allEntries = await this.dndTraverseFileTree(entries);

  const files = await Promise.all(
    allEntries.map(
      (entry) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => entry.file(resolve, reject))
    )
  );

  this.files = new Set(files);

  if (this.files.size > 0) {
    this.progress = this.uploadService.upload(
      this.files, this.currentDir, this.currentProject
    );
  }
}

async dndTraverseFileTree(entries: any[]): Promise<any[]> {
  const dirs = entries.filter(entry => !!entry && entry.isDirectory);
  const files = entries.filter(entry => !!entry && entry.isFile);

  if (dirs.length) {
    const childEntries = (
      await Promise.all(
          dirs.map(dir => new Promise(
            (resolve, reject) => dir.createReader().readEntries(resolve, reject))
          )
        )
    ).flat();

    return this.dndTraverseFileTree(childEntries);
  }

  return [ ...files ];
}
```

Comment: Why are you writing in TypeScript? There's also a few things that can still be simplified here, and you also have a syntax error within `allEntries.map(...)`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Right, you are most welcome to make your own answer, or suggests edits on my answer. Your comment is a bit useless :) Also, how is `allEntries.map` a syntax error?

Comment: Being above 10k, I can't suggest edits, I can only make them, and seeing as the edits are not trivial, nor brief enough to put in a comment. I'll just go ahead and make them since you're inviting.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I'm sorry for your work, but I decided to revert it. The OP is using angular, and therefore must be using `TypeScript`. Some updates you made will result in code failure, and some will result in strict errors in typescript. I don't like that :) I like everything to be strictly typed (which in my answer it already is not, but you know...). I did use your shorter resolve, even though I believe it reduces readability. And your `flat()`, although it would need a change to your target in tsconfig

Comment: You've still neglected error handling. Errors will end up causing your `await`s to stall indefinitely with this code.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts no they won't, they will just go up to the `dndDropFiles`. In which there can be a `try, catch` block, but let's have the OP do some work as well :)

Comment: Wrong, the error callback doesn't have anything to call, so your constructed promises will never reject.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts ohhh, that's a nice catch. You are absolutely right, didn't realise that. I just thought those functions would throw errors :), not require an error callback

Comment: @PierreDuc  Thank you for this.  It has me headed in the right direction.  Something that I forgot to mention is that I need to keep the file structure if there are directories in directories.  But in looking at this I realize I am going to have to change my api to accommodate that anyway.  This code though lets me move forward and helps me learn.